# How can I run time event in laravel 8 in given date and time from mysql

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to give a date and time on my schedule and when that date and time come to execute some function in my example here how is looks my `Kernel.php`

```
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $events = Event::all();
   
    foreach($events as $event){
        $schedule->job(new ListenEvent)
        ->when(function() use ($event){
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if(strtotime($now) == strtotime($event->event_date)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        })
        ->onSuccess(function(Stringable $output){
            echo "Event sent successfully ". $output;
        })->onFailure(function(Stringable $output){
            echo "Event failed to sent: " . $output;
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my job file `ListenEvent.php` what need to do

```
public function handle()
    {
        $events = Event::all();
        $users = User::all();
        
        foreach($users as $user){
            foreach($events as $event){
                $data = json_encode(
                    array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            'channel' => 'sms',
                            'to' => `$user->user_phoneNumber`,
                            'content' => `$event->event_name`
                        ),
                    )
                );

                sendSMS($data);
            }
        }
        
    }
```

How can I achieve sending messages at a given time for example now in my DB date and time on task to run is inserted like this "`2022-03-24 17:45:00`"

Answer (score 0):

```
$events = Event::where('event_date',now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:00'))->get();

$events->each(function($event) use($schedule) {
        $schedule
          ->job(new ListenEvent)
          ->onSuccess(function(Stringable $output){
            echo "Event sent successfully ". $output;
          })
          ->onFailure(function(Stringable $output){
            echo "Event failed to sent: " . $output;
          });
}
```

Comment: not working at all

Comment: Does it get any events after the first query?  It should just get events where the date and time matches.  Since the seconds could be different you may need to amend as per my edit